# installing FOSElasticaBundle using composer error

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, foselasticabundle

I have the following composer.json: http://pastebin.com/qtpJHqbW
However when I tried to run composer: update I get the following error:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package raulfraile/ladybug-bundle == 9999999-dev could not be found.
  Problem 2
    - Can only install one of: mopa/bootstrap-bundle[2.3.x-dev, 3.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: mopa/bootstrap-bundle[3.x-dev, 2.3.x-dev].
    - Installation request for mopa/bootstrap-bundle 2.3.x-dev -> satisfiable by mopa/bootstrap-bundle[2.3.x-dev].
    - Installation request for mopa/bootstrap-bundle == 3.9999999.9999999.9999999-dev -> satisfiable by mopa/bootstrap-bundle[3.x-dev].

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> for more details.

Read <http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.
```

Here's the [link](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSElasticaBundle) to the bundle repo on github if anyone is interested. Any ideas why?

Comment: upload your composer.lock file also, id did composer install from your composer.json and there was no problem. Also try to update composer ( composer self-update)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are requiring plenty of "dev-master" versions, and at the same time require the  `"minimum-stability": "stable"` - this does not seem to be right.

The error message is complaining about dependencies not being resolvable under these circumstances:

- for whatever reason you seem to be unavailable to access raulfraile/ladybug-bundle in a dev version (which sound weird because you are requiring ~1.0, and 1.0.x versions are registered on packagist.org) - do you have a lockfile in your project?
- something else creates a conflict installing mopa/bootstrap-bundle - either version 2.3 or 3.x can be installed.

You should run the same command with some verbose flags attached: `composer install -vvv` for maximum information. That way you will get presented the packages that create the conflicting install requests.

You could also lower the minimum stability to "dev" and see if that fixes the error. But you should really think about the implications. Although Composer does try hard to enable others to download the exactly same versions that were used when the last update (or initial install) was run, it sounds like a bad idea to allow that many development versions.